# jquery-ui dialog in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using a jquery-ui dialog in my chrome extension.

In the background.js I load (extecuteScript/insertCSS) the jquery-ui.js and relative jquery-ui.css.

It works correctly until web pages in which the extension executes don't use jquery-ui themselves; but when the extension executes in a web page that uses jquery-ui the dialog that my extension shows uses the style of the web page's jquery-ui.

How can I avoid this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Xan,

how did you realized this?

I've tried using search and replace the string "ui-" with my "ST_ui-" both in js and css, but this produce some bad behavior, for example dialog drag and resize don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and used a brute-force approach. Manually prefix all jQuery UI classes with your own prefix, both in the js and the css file.

Please note that your UI can still pick up changes for base classes, so it's not a fully satisfactory solution.

Anyone who knows a better way - please contribute another answer.

Comment: Hi Xan, how did you realized this? I've tried using search and replace the string "ui-" with my "ST_ui-" both in js and css, but this produce some bad behavior, for example dialog drag and resize don't work

Comment: Replace ".ui" instead, or something thereabouts.